# How to solve NullPointerException when I press back Button Press

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I am facing problem is when i press button back , my app is crash. My ScanActivity:

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReader.BarcodeReaderListener {
        BarcodeReader barcodeReader;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
            barcodeReader = (BarcodeReader) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.barcode_scanner);
        }
```

My function to scaning my Qrcode.

```
@Override
        public void onScanned(Barcode barcode) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ScanActivity.this,TicketActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("code",barcode.displayValue.toString() );
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Scaning multiple barcodes

```
@Override
        public void onScannedMultiple(List<Barcode> barcodes) {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBitmapScanned(SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray) {
    
        }
```

Return error.

```
@Override
        public void onScanError(String errorMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,"Error " +errorMessage ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCameraPermissionDenied() {
            finish();
        }
    
    }
```

And Logcat i read it but i cannot found the problem.

```
04-06 12:17:25.871 30393-30393/com.example.mobilevision E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mobilevision,
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.mobilevision/com.example.mobilevision.ScanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread$State java.lang.Thread.getState()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3849)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread$State java.lang.Thread.getState()' on a null object reference
```

Should i need add function onDestroy ?

Comment: There are some results if you search online for your Exception. For example this: https://github.com/AmolGangadhare/flutter_barcode_scanner/issues/133

Comment: @emandt can you add example about java not flutter?